# Selecting a dynamic range of data for a Chart

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook that contains several worksheets. For each worksheet I want to generate a chart based on a specified range of data. The columns for the chart data will always be the same however some worksheets will contain more rows of data than others. The code I have at the moment seems to work fine when there is only one worksheet but when I have several worksheets it is not always selecting the correct data range. I'm new to VBA so any help and advise will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Cht As Chart 

Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Application.GetOpenFilename)

 For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets   
    Dim MyRange1 As String
    Dim MyRange2 As String
    Dim MyRange3 As String
    Dim MyRange4 As String

    MyRange1 = Range([O1], [O1].End(xlDown)).Address
    MyRange2 = Range([Q1], [Q1].End(xlDown)).Address
    MyRange3 = Range([R1], [R1].End(xlDown)).Address
    MyRange4 = Range([S1], [S1].End(xlDown)).Address

    MyString1 = MyRange1 & "," & MyRange2
    MyString2 = MyRange3 & "," & MyRange4
    MyChtRange = MyString1 & "," & MyString2

    Set Cht = Ws.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
    Cht.SetSourceData Source:=Ws.Range(MyChtRange)
    Cht.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
 Next Ws
```

Comment: change `Range(...)` to `Ws.Range(...)`. Btw, using `xlDown` is not reliable. Better to use `xlUp`. See this link for more details: [How to determine last used row/column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Comment: your setting 4 ranges on one sheet and then overwriting them so that all 4 ranges arre on the last  sheet

Comment: @simoco changing to Ws.Range gave me a 'Method Range of worksheet failed' error.

Comment: @Steven Martin I suspect you are right as I seem to be selecting the data range for the previous worksheet. How do I correct this?

Comment: use this: `ws.Range(ws.Range("O1"), ws.Range("O" & rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after

```
For Each Ws In Wb.Worksheets
```

add one line

```
Set Ws = ActiveSheet
```